# Back up Azure configuration

Tags: azure

I am quite new to Azure development. I have been working on a proof of concept using Data Factories. This has been using a free trial account. My question is is there a way to export the configuration of my account (not the data) so it can easily be created in another account? For example, I have created the following resources:
[image]

I would like a way to export the set up of these resources so I can include it with my documentation and another developer in my team could use them to recreate the resources easily. I haven't been able to find a way to do this from my research.

Comment: Have you tried exporting a template from your resource group? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal#export-template-from-a-resource-group

Comment: Thanks @JohanMaes I'll try that

Comment: Exporting Templates isn't supported for Data factories (V2) at the moment! I'll have to write it up well!